# background-image nao esta funcionando

Tags: html, css, img

nao sei o que deu simplesmente parou de mostrar a imagem de fundo.
alguém pode dar uma luz.

```
#fundo{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("img/fundo%20site%20simples.png");
}
```

abaixo o link da pagina

https://thimble.mozilla.org/pt-BR/anonymous/c09d8530-6409-4547-bbdc-daf8a6198945/698942

Comment: cade a imagem `img/fundo%20site%20simples.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *URL* da pasta e a imagem que você inseriu não existem. O seu arquivo `index.css` está na pasta `css` e o seu arquivo `index.html` está um nível abaixo desta pasta, então o que você está tentando fazer é inserir uma imagem dentro da pasta `img` dentro da pasta `css`.

```
  background-image: url("img/fundo%20site%20simples.png");
```

Está pasta `img` não existe dentro da pasta `css`, então é só você voltar um nível usando `../` assim ele vai sair da pasta `css` e vai achar a pasta `img` e achar o arquivo `fundo%20site%20simples.png`.

```
background-image: url("../img/fundo%20site%20simples.png");
```

Comment: Leandro vlw eu tinha esquecido dos ../ JESUS q vergonha :D , vlw msm por me responder :D ajudou muito ja tava tentando fazer gambiarra aqui :P

Comment:  sucesso ae, acontece!

Answer (score 1):

Amigo tem certeza que essa imagem e/ou pasta onde está a imagem realmente existem..?? Se você usar a URL com a pasta e o nome da imagem ele diz que não localiza.. Ex; https://thimble.mozilla.org/pt-BR/anonymous/c09d8530-6409-4547-bbdc-daf8a6198945/698942/img/fundo%20site%20simples.png